# How to use order by desc in mongomodel for rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

Hello I use rails3+mongomodel+mongodb.I can sort data by asc but I don't know how to order by desc

```
@article = Article.where().sort(['title'])
```

This code order by asc.if not use sort() data will select by create date.

How to order by desc

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
 @article = Article.where().order("title desc")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use below:

```
@article = Article.where(..your condition..).order_by(:title => "desc")
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that something like this will work:

```rb
@articles = Article.order('title DESC')
```

When I do that I see the following query generated:

```
find({}, {}).sort([["title", :descending]])
```

So I assume it's using the mongo backend.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can
@article = Article.where().desc(:title)

Answer (score 0):

@articles = Article.where(:order => title.desc)

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
@articles = Article.where(...).order(:title.desc)
```